# Функциональное наследование JS. Передача значения свойства потомкам

Tags: javascript, наследование

Вопрос, как передать значение свойства потомкам? В качестве примера, мне нужно чтобы все потомки сохранили контекст, однако это не сводится к проблеме потери контекста. 
У меня есть архитектура кода:

```
function App() {
   // ~ ... какие-то свойства
   let mWindow = new MainController(this), /* новый экземпляр, для примера передаем в него контекст */
       subController = new SubController();

   let event = new Event('myEvent');
   addEventListener('myEvent', function () {subController.render('add')});

   /* Важный метод */
   this.getEvent(){
      return event; /* вызывает срабатывание addEventListener -> subContrl.render() */
   };

   this.run(){
      mWindow.init();
   }
}

function MainController(app){ /* В данной строке я хочу передать что-то (Например, контекст)*/
   this.app = app; /* сохраняю это*/
   this.content_gen = function(arg) {
      dispatchEvent(this.app.getEvent("main"));
   }
};
   this.init = function (){ /* SOMETHING */};
}

function SubController(){
   MainController.call(this) /* Отнаследовали */
   this.render = function(arg) {console.log(this)}; /*this: {SubController; app = undefined}*/

   /* информация (контекст) в obj.app не передана */
   /* Понятно что я его и не передавал. Как это сделать?*/
   /* По аналогии с тем что выше, получается необходимо создать экземпляр и передать в него this.app*/
   /* Либо же сделать SubController(app), но откуда запишется значение в app??*/

}
```

Возможно, кстати, есть более умный вариант передачи контекста при данной архитектуре (в таком случае добавлю еще один вопрос).

Comment: о каком контексте речь? что возвращает getEvent?

Comment: @Grundy это не дубликат вопроса, ТС спрашивает, как передать контекст через параметр

Comment: @Grundy, вопрос был не о контексте, а в качестве дополнительного. Основной проблемой является то, что указано в названии, а именно передача ЗНАЧЕНИЯ какого-либо свойства родителя его потомку. В примере я использовал контекст, но там может быть произвольные данные

Comment: @AntonGult, переоткрыл. А разве сейчас не падает создание наследника на этой строчке? `MainController.call(this) /* Отнаследовали */`?

Comment: @Grundy, не падает. в консоли MainController содержит app = App {}; наследник MainController'а (SubController) содержит app = undefined. Мне нужно чтобы SubController.app так же содержал App {}

Comment: @AntonGult, эта строчка не может не падать при выполнении, потому что ты пытаешься вызвать метод `getEvent` у `undefined`. Если не падает - очевидно SubController вообще нигде не используется

Comment: @Grundy, внес изменения в пример кода для большей ясности. Появился вызов SubController

Comment: @AntonGult, просто передай `this` так же как и в MainController

Comment: `let mWindow = new MainController(this), 
       subController = new SubController(this);` и сам конструктор сделай как советуют в ответе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо тогда и сам контекст передавать, ведь `MainController` принимает параметр

```
function SubController(app){
   // передаем контекст
   MainController.call(this, app) /* Отнаследовали */
   dispatchEvent(this.func)
}
```

Comment: допустим написал SubController(app). Как аргумент передастся, если нет создания экземпляра? В App() мы передавали через создание экземпляра контроллера и в аргумент записывали this. А наследнику откуда аргумент запишется?

Comment: @AntonGult если вы ни разу не вызываете функцию, то как вообще рассчитываете, что будет какое-то наследование? `SubController` нужно вызвать в любом случае

Comment: @AntonGult либо я не совсем понимаю, что в итоге вы хотите получить